# is it a bad practice to store audioTrack and videoTrack in redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, video-streaming, audio-streaming

Where should you store audio and video streams if you need to create a react/redux conference call app?
It seems like redux state is not a good idea, so you should probably move it to some kind of middleware. But I am not sure if I fully understand how to later access those media streams in component.
Are there any examples how that can be achieved?

Comment: Redux wants to serialize its state and actions for the whole time travel/state machine/undo to work properly. Serializing huge amounts of data, which I'd expect your audio and video tracks to be, doesn't sound lilke a good idea. I would only store data that represents these tracks in the redux store (like IDs, connection URL, whatever you're dealing with).

Comment: I'm not a regular Redux user so I'm not going to post this as an answer... but I see no problems with using media stream tracks this way.  They're not serializable.  As long as Redux can handle the reference, it's fine.  I do similar things with other frameworks.